# solution for the flipping coin issue

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, coin-flipping

I am trying to solve this prolem :
 a random experiment of tossing a coin 10000 times and determine the count of Heads::
defining a binomial distribution with `n = 1` and `p = 0.5`. using  binom function from scipy.stats setting random seed to 1 
Draw a sample of 10000 elements from defined distribution. Assume the values 0 and 1 represent Heads and Tails respectively.

Counting the number of heads and display it by using 'bincount' method,

the code snippet is :

```
import scipy as sp
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

n, p = 1, .5  # number of trials, probability of each trial
s = np.random.binomial(n, p, 1000)
print(s)
k = np.bincount(s)


print(k[0])
print(k[1])
print(k.count(1))
```

Where it is going wrong? I need to find out the number of heads from `bincount()`

Comment: How do you know it's wrong? What output do you get and what should it be?

Comment: *where it is going wrong* you have not told us what makes you think something is going wrong

Comment: basically it expects the number of occurrence of heads to be printed using bincount . i am printing both the occurrences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 10000 trials, then change `n, p = 1, .5` to `n, p = 10000, .5`

Comment: thanks Joel. I overlooked that and count() was not correctly used. Thanks , The problem is resolved.